# MacOS X Unzipping All Zip or Tar Files into Subfolders

Tags: unix

I just want to share some pain today. I wanted to unzip files each to separate folders and after some findings, things that work on Ubuntu does not work on Mac OS X.

Comment: what do you mean by "_share some pain_" ?  do you mean that you went through a lot of trouble to figure out how to accomplish this and shared your answer?  If so please look at [It's ok to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and improve both answer and question to fit with SO standards.

Answer (score -1):

You can finish it using this

```
while read -rd $'\0' f; do unzip -d "${f%.*}" "$f";  done < <(find ./ -name "*.zip" -print0)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to the answer.